# Payments Storage, Structure fields

Tags: mysql, database-design

I'm working on existing script which stores payments in a database like below.

```
ID
CLIENT_ID
PAYMENT DESCRIPTION
PAYMENT_DATE_DAY
PAYMENT_DATE_MONTH
PAYMENT_DATE_YEAR
PAYMENT_AMOUNT
```

Any advice or opinion on whether to continue in this way?
Or is better replace the fields with a single DATE field?

Comment: I can't think of a good reason to store dates this way. I could see storing the date AND these fields only in the event that a date part is often needed in the results and you don't want to spare the tiny amount of cpu taken to calculate it.

Answer (score 1):

Do *not* store parts of a date in separate columns.  When you need the parts, compute them.  There are plenty of functions to facilitate this.  Don't mention performance; in nearly every situation, performance is better the way I suggest.